# Thin strip of cloth that holds belt to pants

Tags: single-word-requests

Pants usually have 5-7 narrow (~1cm) short (~5cm) vertical strips of cloth that that hold the belt to the pants:

[image]

What is a single word/short expression for those strips?

I found [`belt loop`](http://visualdictionaryonline.com/clothing-articles/clothing/mens-clothing/pants.php#belt-loop13061), but when I google it, the search seems to indicate that `belt loop` refers to a loop around the belt that attaches *things* to *belt*, **not** *belt* to *pants*.

Is there a more specific term than *belt loop*?

Comment: Yup, they're belt loops.

Comment: That's what I call 'em.

Comment: The phrase can be uses in both senses that you have encountered, but there is rarely much to say about belt loops in the sense that you are asking about; that's why the results of Internet searches for that phrase  are mostly about belt loops in the other sense.

Comment: Yes, belt loops, but if you know the context, just loops is enough. What you found is: belt hooks, People attach hooks to their belt loops, full of keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Googled "parts of trousers" and got this

[image]
[source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/508766089148127770/)

Comment: But there are other results indicating the other usage/usages (belts have loops already to 'take up the slack').